# Extracting all lines from CLOB that begin with a letter or digit

Tags: clob

I am trying to extract from a CLOB only those lines that begin with a letter or a number using REGEXP_SUBSTR
All the lines I want to keep, start with a letter or digit. All the lines I want to delete start with  \ or { or } or are blank.
Here is a sample from the CLOB

```
{\rtf1 \ansi 
{\colortbl;
\red0\green0\blue0;
{\*\generator Apache 
XML Graphics RTF 
Library;}
Customer Screening 
Questionnaire
\par 
}
{\b0 \cf1 \f3 \ri0 \i0 \ql 
}{
{\trowd \itap0 \trleft0 
\clpadt20 \clpadft3 
Originating Source: 
Customer
\cell
```

Many thanks
Anthony

I am using Oracle SQL.

I have tried

```
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '^.*[:alnum:].*$',1,1,'m') 
 from table1
```

but the output I get is
{\rtf1 \ansi
I have tried adding to_clob Fx but with the same output.

Comment: Hello Antony, can you try with [a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+ ?

Comment: Thanks Chris. That unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Hi
I have managed to get a working query looking at a single entry but it is very slow. It takes 8 mins to process with a CLOB of 3500 lines.  
     SELECT
         regexp_substr(txt,'^[^\\|\}|\{].*',1,level,'m') AS clob_data
     FROM
         t_Customer WHERE customer_id=1512
     CONNECT BY
         level <=regexp_count(txt,'[^\\|\}|\{].*');